# Making ajax call to jsp page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am making an ajax call to a jsp page like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#photo').photobooth().on("image", function (event, dataUrl) {
        alert(dataUrl); 
        //alert($('#mygroupuserid'));
        //alert(document.Clickpictures.OwnerId.value);
        //alert(imgdata);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadwebcamimage.jsp',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                encodeimg: dataUrl,
                OwnerId: document.Clickpictures.OwnerId.value,
                OwnerPhone: document.Clickpictures.OwnerPhone.value,
                mobilepass: document.Clickpictures.mobilepass.value,
                emailpass: document.Clickpictures.emailpass.value,
                mypassword: document.Clickpictures.mypassword.value,
                mygroupuserid: document.Clickpictures.mygroupuserid.value

            },
            error : function(){ 
                alert('Error'); 
            },
            success: function(msg){      
                    alert(msg);
            }
        });

        $("#gallery").show().html('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" >');
        });
  });
```

Now in that jsp page i have to make decision basis on some flag value like this :

```
if(flag==true){

    out.println("<script>alert('Face Successfully Detected and Password has been sent');document.location='Main.jsp'</script>");
    }

    else if(flag==false){

    out.println("<script>alert('Sorry,Face Cant Be Detected.Try Again');</script>");

    }%>
```

How can this be achieved.?As this alert box is not being printed right Now.Please help

Comment: How can what be achieved? and what does this flag have to do with the ajax call?

Comment: @developerwjk how to print these alert boxes and move to other jsp page accordingly.And the flag is variable in my current jsp,which decide which way to move on

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the parameter values and check them against what you're expecting:

```
String ownerId = request.getParameter("OwnerId");
if("target".equals(ownerId))
{
  out.println("<script>....");
}
```

And to run the Javascript once it is received in the response on the client side, you must use `eval()`. And you need to fix that missing semi colon in your first JS script.